# How can I get the longitude and lattitude of a specific address not the current address

Tags: android, firebase, geofire, geocoder

I know how to get the current location longitude and latitude and save it in Geofire, but how can I get the longitude and latitude of a specific address and save that instead. I test the code below but nothing is being saved.

What am I doing wrong?

```
String tx7=txt7.getText().toString();

String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("locals");
DatabaseReference update = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);

GeoFire geoFire=new GeoFire(rootRef);

Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(AfterRegistrationActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
String result = null;
List<Address> addressList= null;
try {
    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(tx7, 1);
    Double latt=addressList.get(0).getLatitude();
    Double lonn=addressList.get(0).getLongitude();
    geoFire.setLocation(uid, new GeoLocation(latt, lonn), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
            if (error != null) {


                System.err.println("There was an error saving the location to GeoFire: " + error);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Location saved on server successfully!");
            }
        }
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with geocoder.

```
private void geoLocate(){
    Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: geolocating");

    String yourPlace = mSearchText.getText().toString();

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(YourActivity.this);
    List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
             // passing 1 means you will get one result of that place you can pass any number
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "geoLocate: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
    }

    if(list.size() > 0){
        Address address = list.get(0);

        Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: found a location: " + address.toString());
      // from address object you can get all info like address.latituted etc
        //Toast.makeText(this, address.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: But how would I save that new longitude and latiude to geofire